# How to retain green colour after refreshing a website using javascript

Tags: javascript

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK6SR.png) is the exam question I am trying to answer.

I am a beginner in javascript and also in the web developer field. I am facing a problem: when the webpage refreshes or goes to the next page, the green color on the right resets.

I have already been researching local storage and session storage in html5 but I don't know where to implement this.

Here is my javascript code:

```js
function changeColor(num) {
  var colors = ['rgb(10, 248, 82)', 'rgb(245, 16, 16)', 'rgb(236, 214, 15)']; 
  //green, red, yellow

  document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = colors[num];
}
```

I used `onclick="changeColor(0)"` on the button to ensure the color changes to green.

Comment: Put a CSS rule in the css file ..?

Comment: Inside `changeColor`, persist the color in localStorage with `localStorage.setItem`, then on page load eventually restore it with `var restored = localStorage.getItem(...); if(restored)  changeColor(restored);`